# error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3 in Teamcity

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, cmd, teamcity

I know this kind of error has been posted many times but I never found a clear solution , neither in Google.

I am using `teamcity` (and programming in `C++`) and I get the following message error when I do run:

```
Compilation error: c-interface\build-VS2012\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj 

id=12106;type=TC_COMPILATION_ERROR;identity=c-interface\build-VS_1_1568984478;
additionalData=compileBlockId='64' 
Open in IDE C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(172, 5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.
```

The same code in local compile properly so it's not due to the code , I don't know if it's related to `teamcity` configuration or to build agent in the remote machine or maybe permissions.

I did a build manually and I don't have the same than I had in local.Using a high verbosity a found that the error is coming from :

D:\PortFolioCalculator\BuildAgent\work\7f2ffd93194f947d\c-interface\build-VS2012\Win32\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\custombuild.command.1.tlog

Inside we have that:
setlocal "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:/tortoise6/c-interface -BC:/tortoise6/c-interface/build-VS2012 --check-stamp-list CMakeFiles/generate.stamp.list --vs-solution-file "d:\PortFolioCalculator\BuildAgent\work\7f2ffd93194f947d\c-interface\build-VS2012\rain.sln"

--> there is no cmake 2.8 folder and no c:\tortoise6 folder neither.

My problem is in the repository from where a do a checkout of the code, there is no Win32 folder , this folder is created during the msbuild.2 questions:

How can I change it in order to not having this folder which is only for Visual Studio?

Do you think it's a good idea to tell Teamcity to mute this problem during the compilation?

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: Try going to the build log on the box where the error is and finding the real cause. Does TV check out *all* the dependants? If it trying to read or write to a path that doesn't exist?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I can post the build log, the path really exists and the file Microsoft.CppCommon.targets also


"Win32\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.unsuccessfulbuild".
[08:27:24][c-interface\build-VS2012\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj] CustomBuild
[08:27:25][CustomBuild] The system cannot find the path specified.[08:27:25][CustomBuild] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(172, 5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.

Answer (score 1):

After loosing many days I found the solution.
The cmake is always running. for each build running in teamcity we must do a cmake, so 2 steps are mandatory:
1- in the teamcity folder (it must exist and be already properly populated)of the project I run cmake\bin\cmake.exe -D__TEAM_CITY=1 .. 
the cmake.exe is a binary included inside the project (or install it in the build machine).
2- then : MSbuild TeamCity/file.sln

The build has been performed correctly in teamcity

Comment: Hi me too facing the same situation but in different manner. I have created the solution file using the cmake configure runner through TC. but I could not build the solution using MSbuild. When I tried it locally in VS it showing the same error as you mentioned here like, 
**error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.**
but in build log I have noted that,,
**2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1430,5): warning : The referenced project 'D:/Projects/Core/Libraries/ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj'** does not exist.... 
Will you please help me on this @Zaibacker

Comment: I have checked for the ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj and it is there in the specified path.